# How do I achieve this screenprint-like effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

how would I go about replicating a similar effect to the one shown here in photoshop? It seems sort of like a duotone effect, but I like how there is some texture and you can see the dark grey coming through the yellow dots. How did they do it?

[image]

Comment: Relevant (for the gray dots): https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/38328/63979

Comment: It's not "dark grey coming through yellow" it's merely a black texture on top of the yellow. Can you show us what you've tried? Where you are struggling?

Comment: You could use a [gradient map](https://www.technokids.com/blog/technology-skills/gradient-map-duotone-photoshop/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a hand drawn sketch, preferebably one that has solid black lines and also some degree of shading. The shading of the drawing is where the texture is coming from. Obviously the final result is going to depend greatly on the original artwork.

Set the foreground colour to black, and the background colour to yellow.

Apply *Filter > Sketch > Halftone Pattern*

Example

[image]

A levels adjustment on the result will give you areas of solid yellow without dots

[image]